# How to pip install git repository with requirements

Tags: python, pip

So I have a common library repository which looks something like:

```
common
    __init__.py
    foo
        __init__.py
        bar.py
README.md
requirements.txt
setup.py
```

In a separate project I have it in requirements.txt like this:

```
git+https://github.com/something/something.git#egg=common
```

When I do pip install it installs it to:

```
venv
    src
        common
```

The problem is, the common library has its own requirements.txt file.

How to tell pip to install requirements of the external library?

Comment: Why don't you define the requirements of the library in `setup.py` (in the `setup` call, the `requires` arg).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you pip install it uses `setup.py` of the downloaded package to find dependencies, as opposed to running `"-r requirements.txt"`.

Changing the `setup.py` of common to define dependencies is what you're after.

For an example of defining `install_requires` in your `setup.py` file, see the [Hitchhiker's Guide to Packaging](http://web.archive.org/web/20131213140938/http://guide.python-distribute.org/creation.html).

Answer (score 0):

`pip -r <file|url>` supports eitehr a local file or a url. e.g:

```
pip install -r http://localhost:8080/requirements.txt
```

Tested and confirmed.