# how to download all the python packages mentioned in the requirement.txt to a folder in linux using python idle?

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, pip

I want to download all the python packages mentioned in the requirement.txt to a folder in Linux. I don't want to install them. I just need to download them.

I want to write a python script that can download all the python packages.

python version is 3.6

list of packages in the requirement.txt

```
python-ldap==3.2.0
python-libnmap==0.6.2
python-otrs==0.4.3
pytz==2015.4
PyYAML==3.11
query-string==0.0.2
queuelib==1.2.2
redis==2.10.3
requests==2.22.1
requests-aws4auth==0.9
requests-oauthlib==0.5.0
requests-toolbelt==0.5.0
scp==0.10.2
six==1.10.0
South==1.0.1
tlslite==0.4.9
u-msgpack-python==2.1
urllib3==1.14
w3lib==1.12.0
websockets==3.3
Werkzeug==0.10.4
xlrd==1.0.0
XlsxWriter==1.0.5
zope.interface==4.1.2
GitPython==2.1.3
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pip install git repository with requirements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20578146/how-to-pip-install-git-repository-with-requirements)

Comment: There's not much difference between installing and downloading. You could simply install all the packages to a virtualenv & get the packages from the `site-packages` folder

Answer (score 0):

```
import subprocess
import sys
command = [
    sys.executable,
    '-m',
    'pip',
    'download',
    '--dest',
    'path/to/target',
    '--requirement',
    'path/to/requirements.txt',
]
subprocess.check_call(command)
```

---

**References**:

- https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#using-pip-from-your-program
- [Installing python module within code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12332975/installing-python-module-within-code)
- https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_call
- https://snarky.ca/why-you-should-use-python-m-pip/

Comment: @SmrutiSahoo Does that answer your question? Anything you might want to be clarified before accepting this answer?

Answer (score -1):

Just download the packages?

Then you can use `pip` command

```
pip download <package name>==<version>
```

If you want to make a python script, you can use `subprocess`

```
subprocess.check_call([sys.executable, '-m', 'pip', 'download', 
'<packagename>==<version>'])
```

Comment: I do not want to do it manually. I want to write a script which can do it for me.

Comment: well, you can use a subprocess to run pip command, (answer edited)

Comment: Doesn't seem to answer the question.

Answer (score -1):

Usually you'd use:

```
pip install --target=/path/to/install/to -r requirement.txt
```

This should download all packages in requirement.txt to the path you specify.

Comment: Doesn't seem to answer the question.

Comment: Seems like you're still missing this bit of the question: "_I want to **write a python script** that can download all the python packages_".

Comment: As a .whl or installed package